# MSBuild - How do I use Visual Studio to create/edit a build script?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I can't seem to find how to create an MSBuild script from within Visual Studio. Anyone know how? I'm using VS Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any trouble (VS 2010 Premium).  A standard MSBUILD file is an XML file, so opening it using File -> Open -> File should open it in the XML editor in VS.  Then you can edit, add it to a project or whatever as you need.

I'm not sure if you need a certain edition for the Intellisense to work.

Comment: There is no standard template for target files or build files. So you need to create a standard XML file.

Answer (score 7):

Start with this as a skeleton for your file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
   ToolsVersion="4.0"
   DefaultTargets="Build">

   <Target Name="Build">
      <Message Text="Building..." />
   </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the file extension is .msbuild and not .xml this will enable the intellisense.

Comment: To be accurate, adding the xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the project node is what enables intellisense

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this awesome tool: http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild itself is pretty straightforward so it is pretty simple to do it in any `text/xml` editor.

BTW, MSDN [Walkthrough: Creating an MSBuild Project File from Scratch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx) does not tell anything about Visual Studio and just provides tips how-to write script in editor.